# "Weak headings" on HTML/CSS table

Tags: html, css

When the browser window is made smaller, I would like my HTML table to shrink as far as possible without "losing" content from the TD cells. The header cells (TH elements) can shrink as much as necessary, even if their content is no longer completely visible.

The **desired** behavior is this:

*Narrow* Window, headings partly obscured, content completely visible:
[image: weak headings narrow]

*Wide* Window, everything visible:
[image: weak headings wide]

I tried using `overflow: hidden;` on the TH cells, but it has no effect. Here is [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L11sez3j/2/).

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible with tables. But you could create a custom table using Flexbox

Comment: font-size:2vw;something like that?

Comment: I would take a different approach for small screens - rendering the content is visible as possible, instead of hiding it. I highly recommend tablesaw, it's fantastic: https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw

Answer (score 3):

Set `max-width: 0` for the `th` elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/L11sez3j/3/

Comment: This solves the problem for narrow screens, but if we are on a wide screen, the available space is not used to display all headings. Instead, the last heading simply gets most of the space, and the first two are still cut off. Test by setting `.bounds` width to 600px.